# How to use action_restart in rasa_core version 0.10.4

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am using rasa core version 0.10.4

At the end of the flow I want to add action_restart(default action) so that it will start new conversation when the end reached.

**The story is like:**

```
## Story_help_gnh
* button_option{"option_type":"gifts and hospitality"}
 - utter_help_gnh
> gifts_and_hospitality

## Story_gnh_ethics_counsellor
> gifts_and_hospitality
* ethics_counsellor
 - utter_gnh_ethics_counsellor
 - action_restart
```

For me action_restart is not working in 0.10.4 version. I tried using 0.11.12 version, it is working.

I can't migrate code from 0.10.4 version to 0.11.12 version.

Can anyone help me with:

1. Does 0.10.4 version provides action_restart default action?
2. If yes how to use it. If no is there any alternative way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with Rasa Core version `0.10.4` and `action_restart` worked for me.

My stories:

```
## Story1
* greet
  - utter_hello
  - action_restart
```

My domain file:

```
intents:
  - greet

actions:
  - utter_hello

templates:
  utter_hello:
  - text: "Hi"
  utter_restart:
  - text: "I just restarted"
```

If then talk to the bot:

[image]

So `0.10.4` has a `action_restart` and you can simple add it as `action_restart` to your domain file. You can also add some custom text to the restart if you define a template `utter_restart`.

In general I recommend switching to the latest versions of Rasa Core. The step from `0.10.x` to `0.11` is bit cumbersome as there were some architectural changes, but brings a ton of new features. Also their were none or only little breaking changes after `0.11`.